# Excel VBA Autofill using Coordinate range

Tags: excel, vba, coordinates, autofill

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I'm attempting to Autofill a column range "AB1 - say "AB30" with "=TIME(INT(H1/100),MOD(H1,100),0)" using coordinates so I can change AB30. I've looked through much of the code here but nothing has completely worked. I've tried to modify the code but I am unable to get it to work. After it runs then I'm formatting the same as "General". Thank you for any help you can provide.

This code does what I want but I need to be able to change AB30 with **TRows** = TextBox1.Value

```
Cells(1, 28).Value = "=TIME(INT(H1/100),MOD(H1,100),0)"
Range("AB1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB1:AB30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Columns("AB:AB").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
Cells(1, 28).Value = "=TIME(INT(H1/100),MOD(H1,100),0)"
Range("AB1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1,28).Autofill
    Destination:=Range(35,28), Type:=xlFillDefault
Columns("AB:AB").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

Comment: `Range("AB1:AB" & TextBox1.Value).Formula = "=TIME(INT(H1/100),MOD(H1,100),0)"`

Comment: Thank you Scott. Your suggestion worked. I first put in my variable TRows in place of the TextBox1.Value and it didn't work. I then changed it back which works. I guess I have to pull my number directly from the textbox. Sometimes its the simplest thing that breaks code.